# TaskCompletionSource<TResult> is always null

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
public class MyEventTest {

    private TaskCompletionSource<MyResultObj> _tcs
        = new TaskCompletionSource();

       // somewhere else...
       myEventObj.MyEvent += (sender, args) => {
            _tcs.SetResult(args);
       }

       // somewhere else...
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            MyResultObj obj = _tcs.Task.Result; // should wait until result is set
            obj.ToString() // BOOM! Task is completed, but result is null?!

       }
```

What could be the reason behind this problem?

Comment: why do you think the code will wait??  I see nothing here that would tell me that anything is "waiting..."

Comment: you need to show more code.

Comment: @TMcKeown See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx "The attempt to get the result of t1 blocks the current thread until the completion source gets signaled. "

Comment: How about placing `Debug.Assert(args != null)` before calling `_tcs.SetResult(args)`, does it pass (I expect not)?